# Heroku container:release throwing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

Tags: java, docker, heroku

I am trying to deploy my docker image(spring boot) on heroku .It is successfully pushed to heroku but when i am running release command it is throwing the following error :-

```
 C:\Users\dell i5\git\petCare1\config>heroku container:release web -a petconfig
(node:152776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected response to be s
uccessful, got 422
    at Request.handleFailure [as _handleFailure] (C:\Program Files\heroku\client
\node_modules\heroku-client\lib\request.js:254:11)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\heroku-c
li-util\lib\command.js:56:12)
    at concat.then (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\heroku-client\li
b\request.js:148:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
(node:152776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. Thi
s error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catc
h block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejecti
on id: 1)
(node:152776) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are dep
recated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate t
he Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Releasing images web to petconfig... !
 !    No command specified for process type web
```

**Update:- I am using windows 8 laptop for heroku deployment and version of heroku is as follows:-**

```
C:\Users\dell i5\git\petCare1\config>heroku version
heroku/7.30.1 win32-x64 node-v11.14.0
```

Command.js file from heroku-util :-

// safety check for if we have already seen this request for preauthing

```
  // this prevents an infinite loop in case some preauth fails silently
    // and we continue to get two_factor failures

    // this might be better done with a timer in case a command takes too long
    // and the preauthorization runs out, but that seemed unlikely
    if (res.statusCode === 403 && body.id === 'two_factor' && !preauths.requests.includes(this)) {
      let self = this
      // default preauth to always happen unless explicitly disabled
      if (options.preauth === false || !body.app) {
        twoFactorPrompt(options, preauths, context)
          .then(function (secondFactor) {
            self.options.headers = Object.assign({}, self.options.headers, {'Heroku-Two-Factor-Code': secondFactor})
            self.request()
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            self.reject(err)
          })
      } else {
        preauths.requests.push(self)

        // if multiple requests are run in parallel for the same app, we should
        // only preauth for the first so save the fact we already preauthed
        if (!preauths.promises[body.app.name]) {
          preauths.promises[body.app.name] = twoFactorPrompt(options, preauths, context)
            .then(function (secondFactor) {
              return cli.preauth(body.app.name, heroku(context), secondFactor)
            })
        }

        preauths.promises[body.app.name].then(function () {
          self.request()
        })
          .catch(function (err) {
            self.reject(err)
          })
      }
    } else {
      this._handleFailure(res, buffer)
    }
```

Comment: This is an error in JavaScript, not Java.`request.js:254:11`

Comment: This does not relate to Docker, you have an unhandled promise in your JavaScript

Comment: The project the i is one java only,for the same project i have made the docker image and if you see the error is coming inside the installed folder of heroku

Comment: Maybe you deployed using a Windows 10 laptop, that doesn't make it related to windows 10. You could start by debugging line 254 pf `request.js` to see where the unhandled promise is. But it's impossible for us to tell without seeing the code

Comment: I have updated the question with the source code of heroku command.js file

Comment: The unhandled promise is most likley somewhere in your JS code. Do you have any promises that do not handle errors? E.g `catch(error)`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `heroku update` and then run the command again